# I need to generate a mathematical formula based on two references

Tags: math

I am in the Go environment.
I am looking for a cross platform library to use to generate my two formulas in python or F # or matlab, ...

I need to generate a mathematical formula based on two references

The manufacturer indicates that the value of a sensor is coded on a byte and is between 0 and 255.

The minimum = 0 and has the representation value -60dB
The maximum = 255 and has a representation value of +20dB

I must now generate two formulas:

- RX: a mathematical formula allowing me to interpret the value coming from the sensor in value of representation in dB.
- TX: the inverse of RX ie a mathematical formula allowing me to convert the value of representation in dB in value of representation of the sensor.

If you have a idea it is welcome

Youssef

Comment: Is the mapping between byte value and dB value linear? If not, you need first a formula to describe the relationship between them. This would be out of the scope of this site.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, excellent question! I provided an answer assuming that is what he wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you need a linear relationship, so you can use the following code:

```
INPUT_MIN = 0
INPUT_MAX = 255
OUTPUT_MIN = -60
OUTPUT_MAX = 20

SLOPE = (OUTPUT_MAX - OUTPUT_MIN) / (INPUT_MAX - INPUT_MIN)

def rx(sensor_input):
    return SLOPE * (sensor_input - INPUT_MIN) + OUTPUT_MIN

def tx(dbs):
    return (dbs - OUTPUT_MIN) / SLOPE + INPUT_MIN
```

What you have to do is to find the equation of the line given those two points. There are many tutorials online about it like [this one](http://www.coolmath.com/algebra/08-lines/12-finding-equation-two-points-01).

Once you have found the equation in which `y` would be the variable that represents your output, and `x` represent your input, you need to find `x` in terms of `y`. Finally, you just implement both functions.

Note that I haven't limited the input, so in case you want restricted input values, I encourage you to add some conditionals in the functions.

Answer (score 0):

In python using numpy:

```py
import numpy as np

def RX(input_val):
    # use linspace to create lookup table
    lookup_array = np.linspace(-60,20,255)
    return lookup_array(int(input_val))

def TX(decibal_value):
    # use linspace to create lookup table
    lookup_array = np.linspace(-60,20,255)
    # find the index closest to decibal value by searching for the smallest difference 
    index = (np.abs(spectum - decibal_value)).argmin()
    return index
```